# Is it possible to disable html inside a frame or embedded video? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video-streaming

I'm creating a website which is for video streaming. Most of the videos shown on my website were embedded from different video hosts. I found out that these embedded videos have heavily annoying ads on it that forces you to click before you can actually play the video. That reduces the quality of the video to the users. This is the screenshot of the video.
[image]

Ads were placed on the center that forces you to click before you can play the video.
I look at the source code and this is what I found.
[image]

Is it possible to hide or disable the `html` inside the `iframe`? Or any other solutions (scripts) to hide these on the video. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

bodi0 offered the best solution, however you can also tell the viewer to use adblock or any "css changing" plugin like Stylish, grab the ads' class / id and make it display: none;

however, these ads are what keep your video service free. They paid for the service hosting and maintenance fee. If you feel the need to go ad free, consider getting a premium account.

Comment: Upvoted for the second paragraph. The informal contract between users and sites with ads is "You can view out content if you look at our ads." That is what keeps the site free, and if you don't like the ads you should look for content elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you need to do couple of things:

1. Parse the URL and get the contents of the `iframe` (via `curl` functions will be fastest, if you use PHP).
2. Using PHP (or other scripting language) RegEx filter and inject CSS, which will overwrite the old code and it will replace the ads (or hide them).
3. Save the modified page content in a variable and include it in your script file, where you output the video page content.

However the exact answer to your question is impossible, because your question is too broad.
Also keep in mind, that this procedure *may* be illegal (copyrights violations mostly), if you do not have explicit consent from the owner of the videos, because you grab and modify the contents from his website.

Comment: The question simply means, how to disable ads inside the embedded video.